# how does this function work? (reverse string)

Tags: python

```
def reverse(text):
    y = ""
    for i in text:
        y = i + y
    return y
```

How does this function return the reverse string of the input?
I can't seem to grasp the concept.

Comment: Try to print `i` and `y` in the loop and see for yourself.

Comment: `i` (each character of `text`) is added *in front* of `y` (every previous character of `text` already seen)

Comment: Try using e.g. http://pythontutor.com/ (or just a piece of paper and a pen), and step through it to see what happens.

Comment: I find the downvotes surprising. Although the question might be considered _easy_ by a journeyman developer or interested student, there might be a reason for this question being asked. It satisfies the criteria for a valid question in terms of self-containment, verifiability, an actual question being asked instead of just presenting a fuzzy problem, et cetera.

Comment: @Codor: I didn't downvote, but I don't see any research effort (and that's a legitimate reason for a downvote). Maybe the OP should have explained where he failed when he tried to track the flow of the program.

Comment: @Matthias I partly agree with you; my point was more that the question might be asked in the best way possible, assuming a relatively low experience of the user in the particular subject and programming in general. Although being relatively easy to answer given a rough understanding of the language features themselves (which I admittedly don't really have myself), the question (involving a piece of code which seems artificial, indicating participation in some learning process) differs from other 'low-quality' questions in the 'gimme teh code fix plz' style.

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't actually know Python in particular, apparently the reversal works by iterating over the individual characters of the input in a forwardly fashion. Before, a result variable `y` is initialized. During the iteration, the individual characters are inserted at the *beginning* of the result variable, which means that the first characters comes to be be positioned at the end and the last character is appended at the beginning of the result variable. Finally, the result variable is returned.

Answer (score 0):

y starts as an empty string. Then you iterate over the characters of text from left to right, and add each character as the suffix of y. In other words, you iterate over text from left to right, and add it to y from right to left